# @RequestBody annotation not working in Spring and give NoSuchMethodError erro

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Through angular I am sending update request to SPRING in controller I have method to map this request but in this @RequestBody not able to map to my class and give

**Error:**

```
**2017-10-06 12:42:43.496 ERROR 5856 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.constructType(Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;] with root cause**

**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.constructType(Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;**

**at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.getJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:319) ~[spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]**

**at org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.canRead(TypeConstrainedMappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:63) ~[spring-hateoas-0.19.0.RELEASE.jar:na]**
```

But I have check in **com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory** class their is method

```
@Deprecated
public JavaType constructType(Type type, Class<?> contextClass) {
    TypeBindings bindings = (contextClass == null)
            ? TypeBindings.emptyBindings() : constructType(contextClass).getBindings();
    return _fromAny(null, type, bindings);
}
```

**Angular Request Code**

```
function updateActivityByActivityID(ENDPOINTS, ActivityID, bodyJSON) {
        var url = ENDPOINTS.SERVICE_ADDRESS
            + ENDPOINTS.UPDATE_ACTIVITY_BY_ACTIVITY_ID
            + ActivityID;
        return HttpHandler.PUT(url, bodyJSON);
    }
```

*url :* http://localhost:8080/Integration/Activity/updateCron/14

*bodyJSON :* cronExpression: "0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *"

**Controller Code**

```
@ApiOperation(value = "update Activity scheduled expression")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, path = "/Integration/Activity/updateCron/{activityID}", produces = "application/json")
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = String.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Failure") })
@ResponseBody
public IntegrationProcessResultVO updateActivityScheduledExpression(
        @PathVariable("activityID") Long activityID,
        @RequestBody ScheduledSetupVO scheduledSetupVO)
        throws ActivityNotFoundException, IOException,
        ActivitySchedulerException {

    System.out.println("Activity ID : "+activityID);
    System.out.println("Request Body : "+scheduledSetupVO);

    IntegrationProcessResultVO integrationProcessResultVO = activityService
            .updateActivityCronExpression(activityID, scheduledSetupVO);

    return integrationProcessResultVO;
}
```

**ScheduledSetupVO Class**

```
package com.data.integration.service.vo;

public class ScheduledSetupVO {

private String cronExpression;

public ScheduledSetupVO(String cronExpression) {
    super();
    this.cronExpression = cronExpression;
}

public ScheduledSetupVO() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public String getCronExpression() {
    return cronExpression;
}

public void setCronExpression(String cronExpression) {
    this.cronExpression = cronExpression;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.toString();
}
```

}
**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<name>dataintegrationservice</name>
<description>Data Integration</description>
<url>http://iquantifi.com/</url>
<groupId>com.data.integration</groupId>
<artifactId>dataintegrationservice</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<!-- Configures repository location for pentaho libraries -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>pentaho-releases</id>
        <url>https://public.nexus.pentaho.org/content/groups/omni/</url> <!-- Location changed Previous - http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo/ -->
    </repository>
    <repository>

        <id>clojars-releases</id>
        <url>http://clojars.org/repo/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>



<!-- lookup parent from repository -->
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <pentaho.kettle.version>6.1.0.0-192</pentaho.kettle.version>
    <vertx.version>3.3.0</vertx.version>
    <commons.lang.version>3.4</commons.lang.version>
    <jtds.version>1.3.1</jtds.version>
    <pentaho-reporting-version>6.1.0.1-196</pentaho-reporting-version>
    <quartz.version>2.2.3</quartz.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>${jtds.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- pentaho libraries -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
        <artifactId>kettle-core</artifactId>
        <version>${pentaho.kettle.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
        <artifactId>kettle-engine</artifactId>
        <version>${pentaho.kettle.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-kettle</groupId>
        <artifactId>kettle-ui-swt</artifactId>
        <version>${pentaho.kettle.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
        <artifactId>libformula</artifactId>
        <version>${pentaho.kettle.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
        <artifactId>libbase</artifactId>
        <version>${pentaho.kettle.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jar required for Pentaho Transformation/job -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsonpath</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-apache-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.16</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
        <artifactId>janino</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.15</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.enterprisedt</groupId>
        <artifactId>edtFTPj</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- pentaho reporting -->


    <!-- Start pentaho reporting jar dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-reporting-engine</groupId>
        <artifactId>pentaho-reporting-engine-classic-core</artifactId>
        <version>${pentaho-reporting-version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-reporting-engine</groupId>
        <artifactId>pentaho-reporting-engine-classic-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>${pentaho-reporting-version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
        <artifactId>libdocbundle</artifactId>
        <version>${pentaho-reporting-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
        <artifactId>libfonts</artifactId>
        <version>${pentaho-reporting-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
        <artifactId>libformat</artifactId>
        <version>${pentaho-reporting-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
        <artifactId>libloader</artifactId>
        <version>${pentaho-reporting-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
        <artifactId>librepository</artifactId>
        <version>${pentaho-reporting-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
        <artifactId>libserializer</artifactId>
        <version>${pentaho-reporting-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
        <artifactId>libxml</artifactId>
        <version>${pentaho-reporting-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
        <artifactId>libswing</artifactId>
        <version>${pentaho-reporting-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.stripes</groupId>
        <artifactId>stripes</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>rhino</groupId>
        <artifactId>js</artifactId>
        <version>1.7R3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>bsh</groupId>
        <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.barbecue</groupId>
        <artifactId>barbecue</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6d</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>bsf</groupId>
        <artifactId>bsf</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>pentaho-library</groupId>
        <artifactId>libsparkline</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- end of Jar required for Pentaho Transformation/job -->

    <!-- Apache commons util libraries -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>${commons.lang.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Apache commons util libraries end -->
    <!-- Swagger UI -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- end Swagger UI -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- Quartz Scheduler -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>${quartz.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Neo4j JDBC Driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-jdbc-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL connector -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- for NoSuchMethod Error while executing jar -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludeDevtools>true</excludeDevtools>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<scm>
    <url>https://bitbucket.org/kscloud/dataintegrationservice.git</url>
    <connection>scm:git:https://kaniket_kanaka@bitbucket.org/kscloud/dataintegrationservice.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://kaniket_kanaka@bitbucket.org/kscloud/dataintegrationservice.git</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

If I removed the @RequestBody from the controller method then it is working fine

Comment: it looks like version issue. share pom.xml

Comment: @Barath I have shared the pom.xml file please check and suggest me the solution.

Comment: Remove the `com.fasterxml.jackson` dependencies (or at least the `<version>` tag of those). Spring Boot already gives you that.

Comment: @M. Deinum hey this work for me can you write this in answer instead of comment so other may also get help from this.
Once again thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an incompatible Jackson version. You are managing the version yourself don't do that.

Either remove the following dependencies from your `pom.xml` the `spring-boot-starter-web` already adds them. :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
 </dependency>
```

Or at least remove the `<version>` tag from the dependencies so that Spring Boot can manage the version.